# Multiple image sizes | Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to create thumbnails based on an uploaded file, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to achieve this. Now the below code keeps creating thumbnails. `if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {` this part is the problem.

Is there an easier way to create multiple thumbnails based on this example? https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js

```
exports.onFileChange = functions.storage.object()
    .onFinalize((object) => {
        const sizes = [200, 50];
        const timestamp = + new Date();

        sizes.forEach((size, index) => {

            // File and directory paths.
            const filePath = object.name;
            const contentType = object.contentType; // This is the image MIME type
            const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
            let fileName = path.basename(filePath);
            let newFileName = path.basename(filePath)
            let currentThumbURL = '';
            const filename = fileName.substr(0, fileName.indexOf('.'));
            let fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop();

            fileName = filename + timestamp + '.' + fileExtension;

            const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${THUMB_PREFIX}-${size}-${fileName}`));
            const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
            const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
            const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);

            var folder = fileDir.substr(0, fileDir.indexOf('/'));

            if (folder !== 'profile') return null;

            if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
                console.log('This is not a profile image.');
                return null;
            }

            // if (index === sizes.length - 1) {
            // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
            if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {
                console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
                return null;
            }
            // }
            // Cloud Storage files
            const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
            const file = bucket.file(filePath);
            const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);
            const metadata = {
                contentType: contentType,
                // To enable Client-side caching you can set the Cache-Control headers here. Uncomment below.
                // 'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=3600',
            };

            // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
            return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
                // Download file from bucket.
                return file.download({ destination: tempLocalFile });
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
                // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
                return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', `${size}x${size}>`, tempLocalThumbFile], { capture: ['stdout', 'stderr'] });
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
                // Uploading the Thumbnail.
                return bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, { destination: thumbFilePath, metadata: metadata });
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbFilePath);
                // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
                console.log('Delet tempLocalFile', tempLocalFile)
                console.log('Delete tepLocalThumbFile', tempLocalThumbFile)
                fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
                fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
                // Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.
                const config = {
                    action: 'read',
                    expires: '03-01-2500',
                };
                return Promise.all([
                    thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config),
                    file.getSignedUrl(config),
                ]);
            }).then((results) => {

                const thumbResult = results[0];
                const originalResult = results[1];
                const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
                const fileUrl = originalResult[0];

                // Add the URLs to the Database
                ...


            }).then(() => {

                console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database. Delete original uploaded image.')

                // bucket.file(`/profile/${filename}/${filename}.png`)
                //     .delete().then(() => console.log('File deleted'))
                //     .catch(error => console.log(error))
            }

            ).catch(error => console.log(error));
        });
    });
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? `if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX))` should normally not "cause" any error, it just checks that the file that triggered the Cloud Function is not already a Thumbnail. In this case the Cloud Function is stopped since there is no reason to treat this file (since it is already a thumbnail).

Comment: Not error. I shouldn't have said error. Even though the thumbnail is created, it keeps creating more. I would like it to stop after the second iteration.

Comment: Did you modify the code from the example? Normally it should not create more thumbnails.

Comment: I did modify it. I need it to create two thumbnails. A 200x200 thumbnail and a 50x50 thumbnail. I also need it to add a timestamp to the image name. That way the image will refresh.

Comment: What are the file names of your two thumbnails?

Comment: They're the same: `userkey` + `-size-` + `timestamp`. I'm not checking the right filename here `fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our comments above, it seems your problem comes from the fact that you are "not checking the right filename" with `fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)`" since your file names follow the `userkey + -size- + timestamp` pattern.

However, IMHO there is another problem in your code: you are using `sizes.forEach((size, index) => {})` to trigger twice the Cloud Function code.

The original Cloud Function code (from the Firebase official examples) chains several asynchronous operations in order to generate the thumbnail. The original Cloud Function code returns only one promise, the one that resolves at the end of the chain.

If you want to execute this code twice in the Cloud Function, you should modify the chain of promises in order to return only one promise.

---

You may do something along these lines. This is just a **very first draft proposal** on how the asynchronous operations could be duplicated to treat the two files in parallel. There is potentially a lot of room to streamline the code -avoiding repetition- and note that it was not tested at all!)

```
return mkdirp(tempLocalDir)
  .then(() => {
    // Download files from bucket.
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(file_1.download({ destination: tempLocalFile_1 }));
    promises.push(file_2.download({ destination: tempLocalFile_2 }));
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(() => {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(
      spawn(
        'convert',
        [
          tempLocalFile,
          '-thumbnail',
          `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH_1}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT_1}>`,
          tempLocalThumbFile_1
        ],
        { capture: ['stdout', 'stderr'] }
      )
    );

    promises.push(
      spawn(
        'convert',
        [
          tempLocalFile,
          '-thumbnail',
          `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH_2}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT_2}>`,
          tempLocalThumbFile_2
        ],
        { capture: ['stdout', 'stderr'] }
      )
    );

    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(() => {
    //console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Uploading the Thumbnail.

    const promises = [];
    promises.push(
      bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile_1, {
        destination: thumbFilePath_1,
        metadata: metadata
      })
    );
    promises.push(
      bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile_1, {
        destination: thumbFilePath_1,
        metadata: metadata
      })
    );
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbFilePath);
    // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile_1);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile_1);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile_2);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile_2);
    // Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.
    const config = {
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500'
    };
    return Promise.all([
      thumbFile_1.getSignedUrl(config),
      file_1.getSignedUrl(config),
      thumbFile_2.getSignedUrl(config),
      file_2.getSignedUrl(config)
    ]);
  })
  .then(results => {....}}
```

---

In addition, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Yeah. I didn't think it was the right way to create multiple thumbnails. Thank you! I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a **proposal** of modification of the orginal code from the example. This is just a **very first draft** on how the asynchronous operations could be duplicated to treat the two files in parallel. It has not been tested!

Comment: I'll test it. Thank you.

Comment: @Ciprian Hi, did you get the time to work out a solution based on the propsal?

Comment: Hello. No, I realised that the image being uploaded was already resized. So I just created a thumbnail from that. Thank you for your help.